# Progress bar animation does not work on all android devices

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar

I have used the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035682/animate-progressbar-update-in-android) link for progress bar animation, which works fine on all devices except Sony Xperia. Please tell me the solution for the same. Didn't found any.

Call the progress bar animation like below:

```
ProgressBarAnimation anim = new ProgressBarAnimation(progress, from, to);
anim.setDuration(1000);
progress.startAnimation(anim);
```

This is the same way I actually implemented which is working fine on nexus 6, Samsung phones, but not working on Sony Xperia.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/pBar_ht_wd"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/pBar_ht_wd"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pb_mg_top"
    android:visibility="visible"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_circular_bar"
    android:progress="75"
    android:max="100"
    android:secondaryProgress="100"
    android:useLevel="true"/>
```

I want to have below result in the progress bar:

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1RWd.png)

Comment: *does not work* is not enough to describe a programming problem, you need to include stacktraces + excepted and actual behavior. All relevant code should be included in the question itself.

Comment: please check the edit, code has been added to show the animation in progress bar. If you know the solution please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem and for me "does not work" is fair enough explanation for progressdialog, afterall it's not rocket science. It shows but it doesnt run animation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I know my question has marked negative, but if anyone face the same problem, use the github liberary from the below link:

[CustomProgressView](https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView)

Answer (score 1):

In some of the devices, animations were *disabled*. Check if animations are *enabled* in developer settings in your device.