# Progressbar not able to animate horizontally in android

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar, android-animation, objectanimator

I have a horizontal progress bar in splash screen and I am trying to give it horizontal left to right animation. I have tried simple animate method as well as object animator method but it is not working am I doing anything wrong here?

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/splash_progressbar"
    android:progress="1000"
    android:max="1000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="203dp" />
```

java code using object animator.

```
splashProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splash_progressbar);

ObjectAnimator progressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(splashProgress, "progress", 1000, 0);
    progressAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    progressAnimator.start();
```

with simple animate method.

```
    splashProgress.setScaleX(0); splashProgress.setScaleY(0);
    splashProgress.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).start();
```

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: nexus 5 runnning api 23

Comment: And you're trying to set the progress amount right? Not physically move the progress bar view around the screen

Comment: howmuch it should be?

Comment: My bad. My answer used a new method not available in versions less than 24. [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035682/animate-progressbar-update-in-android)

Comment: thank you.. I saw that and it seems to work for everyone but me.. I tried it using the class and set value from 0 to 100. Still progres bar is not moving. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Try calling `setMax(100)` before running the animation and see if it works