# Animate while setBackgroundColor in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-drawer, stepper

I'm working on a custom stepper.
Everything is working fine.

What I want to do now is animate the stepper while filling the current step.

this Image shows my idea:

[image: this Image shows my idea:]

This is my code while setting the color of the line, title, and the icon src:

```
private void DrawStepper(int position) {
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            imgStepShipper.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_current_step);
            txtStepShipper.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkWhite));

            imgStepConsignee.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unselected_step);
            txtStepConsignee.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkSuperWhite));
            line2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkWhite));

            imgStepShipment.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unselected_step);
            txtStepShipment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkSuperWhite));
            line3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkWhite));

            imgStepCharges.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unselected_step);
            txtStepCharges.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkSuperWhite));

            break;

        case 1:
            imgStepShipper.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_step);
            txtStepShipper.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            imgStepConsignee.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_current_step);
            txtStepConsignee.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkWhite));

            imgStepShipment.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unselected_step);
            txtStepShipment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkSuperWhite));
            line3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkWhite));

            imgStepCharges.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unselected_step);
            txtStepCharges.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkSuperWhite));

            break;

        case 2:
            imgStepShipper.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_step);
            txtStepShipper.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            imgStepConsignee.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_step);
            txtStepConsignee.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            imgStepShipment.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_current_step);
            txtStepShipment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkWhite));

            imgStepCharges.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unselected_step);
            txtStepCharges.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkSuperWhite));

            break;

        case 3:
            imgStepShipper.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_step);
            txtStepShipper.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            imgStepConsignee.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_step);
            txtStepConsignee.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            imgStepShipment.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_step);
            txtStepShipment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            line3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            imgStepCharges.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_current_step);
            txtStepCharges.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            break;
    }
}
```

Position is the current step.

and this is my UI:

[image: and this is my UI:]

As I said, I want to animate the line each time a move from step to another.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, u can make that line to be progressBar and animate setting its progress.

This how animation is done:
[Animate ProgressBar update in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035682/animate-progressbar-update-in-android)

Or you can animate the view background, just using drawables with animations, check here:
[Animate change of view background color on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-on-android)