# Android vertical progress bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

How should I make this type of progress bar in android..

**Example Link**
https://dribbble.com/shots/3231407-Progress-Bar-Animated

I want to create this type of progress bar in my android application with same design.

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate ProgressBar update in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035682/animate-progressbar-update-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [git repository.](https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/SwipeCoordinator)

[image]

**Progress Bar (XML Component)**

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/parent_swipeable_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <View
        android:id="@id/swipeable_view"
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**`ProgressListener`**

```
swipeCoordinator.setProgressListener(new SwipeCoordinator.ProgressListener() {
  @Override public void onProgress(float progress) {
    tvAccepted.setScaleX(progress);
    tvAccepted.setScaleY(progress);
    tvAccepted.setAlpha(progress);
  }
});
```

Hope you got the answer here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use default progressbar and just add below code to your progressbar in xml

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:rotation="270"
```

Comment: I already created the vertical progress bar, but i need the same design and progress percentage counting.

Comment: There is  a lot of example lib, you can check it https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Progress.md